# Trying to access a state from another state in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to access a state from another state in react native, like this way :

```
class Subcomponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {
    inputText : <TextInput value={this.state.counter}/>
    counter: 0,
  };

  render(){
    return (
      <View>{this.state.inputText}</View>
    )
  }
}
export default Subcomponent;
```

And I get undefined, I also tried to do it with a string instead of an integer.
Is this just not possible ? Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Refer Redux and MobX for better state management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access state to another state, but this works for you in this code.

```
class Subcomponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {
    counter: 0,
  };

  renderText(){
    return(
      <TextInput value={this.state.counter}/>
    );
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View>{this.renderText()}</View>
    )
  }
}
export default Subcomponent;
```

Comment: I have another question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63023626/how-to-set-an-array-and-get-values-from-key-in-react-native