# How to set an array and get values from key in react native

Tags: react-native

What I would like to do is to set an array as a state for example :

```
state={
array : ['key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3']
};
```

I also would like to access with a method one of the values by its key for example getValue(key1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **Class Components**

```js
class YourClassComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      array: ['key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3']
    };
  }

  getValue = (key) => {
    return this.state.array[key];
  }
}
```

Else in function component with **React Hooks**

```js
import {useState} from 'react'; // <------- Import useState

const YourFunctionComponent = () => {

  const [array, setArray] = useState(['key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3']); //  <------- By default create with these values

  const getValue = (key) => {
   return array[key];
  }

}
```

Comment: How can i set this array as a state please, I'm using a class component